# Import more than 10000 records from excel to sharepoint list using client side scripting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jsom, excel-import

I have 32 columns and 10000 more rows. And i tried using xls.core.min.js to import data to sharepoint list. At a time i can import 4000+ only. After that it got aborted. I have checked the below site. and it clearly tells only 15 columns and 10000 records is the maximum limit.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-a-excel-file-using-html5-jquery/

I dont have access to server for creating excel services to synchronize . I am looking for client side scripting solution. Please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project to read the data from excel which is placed in a library from the same site, I used [ExcelPLus](http://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/API.html#readAll), its a free JavaScript plugin, include that in your SharePoint page and read the content of your excel file very easily. Below code snippet shows how to open and display the content of an excel sheet.

```
var ep=new ExcelPlus();
// we call openRemote()
ep.openRemote("http://my.server.com/path/file.xlsx", function(passed) {
  if (!passed) alert("Error: impossible to load the remote file");
  else alert(ep.selectSheet(1).readAll()) // show the content of the first sheet
})
```

and if you know the range from which you need to fetch the data from excel sheet, then you can use the read function, like below,

read(range, options)

range can be a range (e.g. "A1:D1"), or a single cell (e.g. "A1")